# How to handle exceptions on InfegrationFlows?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have this flow connected thru Spring Cloud DataFlow. One microservice gets the email from a queue and sends to this other microservice that should send the email.

I want to be able to catch failed emails and have the original message before .transform() and the exception message.

How to do it?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sendMailFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Sink.INPUT)
            .transform(Transformers.converter(converter))
            .handle(Mail.outboundAdapter(EmailSinkApplication.this.props.getServer())
                            .port(EmailSinkApplication.this.props.getPort())
                            .credentials(EmailSinkApplication.this.props.getUser(), EmailSinkApplication.this.props.getPass())
                            .protocol(EmailSinkApplication.this.props.getProto())
                            .javaMailProperties(p -> {
                                p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                                p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                            }),
                    e -> e.id("sendMailEndpoint"))
            .get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to implement a `ChannelInterceptor` and add your logic into the `afterSendCompletion()`. Use a `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` on this interceptor bean to specify a `patterns` as a `Sink.INPUT`. So, you are going to have a `try..catch` around the whole flow on that `Sink.INPUT` channel.

Comment: Like this: `IntegrationFlows.from(Sink.INPUT).intercept(interceptor)`  and `interceptor` is injected and annotated with `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` implementing ChannelInterceptor and on afterSendCompletion if the exception argument is not null, I add my exception logic?

Comment: Yes, it also going to work. Good catch! No, you don't need a `@GlobalChannelInterceptor` for that case then. True, you need to check for the `exception` in your method. Since this `afterSendCompletion()` is called for normal pass, too.